# Excel: Macro affects multiple columns in table when I only want it to affect a specific one

Tags: excel, vba, list, dropdown

I created a table in Excel that has two columns (C and H) with a dropdown list that each reference a different list (see image below). I found a macro that allows you to select multiple names from a list and seperates them with a comma as they are added. This works great for the column I want this to work for (Column C: "Responsible"). However, I realized that the code also applies itself to Column H: "Status" which is not what I intended. I thought that I restricted it to just Column C the way that the macro is written. Could you help me find a way to fix it so that it only applies to the "Responsible" Column? Also the table is connected to a chart. I wanted to make sure that the macro would dynamically apply to the table as it shrinks/expands since tasks can be added or removed. The code does that already, however I'm open to suggestions to make it more efficient/neat. I have provided the macro below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cht As Chart
Dim varValues As Variant
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Dim lType As Long

Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart
varValues = cht.SeriesCollection(2).XValues

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

lType = Target.Validation.Type
If lType = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row > cht.SeriesCollection(2).Points(LBound(varValues) + 1) And Target.Row < cht.SeriesCollection(2).Points(UBound(varValues) + 1) Then
        If oldVal = "" Then
        Else
            If newVal = "" Then
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                Ar = Split(oldVal, ", ")
                strVal = ""
                For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                    Debug.Print strVal
                    Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
                    If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
                        strVal = strVal
                        lCount = 1
                    Else
                        strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ", "
                    End If
                Next i
                If lCount > 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 2)
                Else
                    Target.Value = strVal & newVal
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This is an image of what the table looks like. I have highlighted a row that shows the problem I am having in Column H.

[image]

Comment: How is the range `Target` defined?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad It's in the `Worksheet_Change()` event. Furthemore `Target.Count > 1` is a condition at the top to end the routine if more than one cell has been changed triggering the event.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause this. That `If Target.Column = 3` is pretty clear. I can't imagine a scenario where that would allow `H` through. Can you toss a breakpoint on that `IF` statement and see what the `target.column` value is when `H` is being affected?

Comment: @JNevill The column value is coming back as 8 (as expected), so I still have no clue how it's coming through.

Comment: Is there some way to see deleted answers? I want to figure out who the user was that recently deleted their answer because while it did not work, they led me in the right direction and I wanted to credit them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this made a difference, but re-arranging the `If Target.Column = 3` statement by moving it up made the code work as desired. I used -----> <----- to show the change.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cht As Chart
Dim varValues As Variant
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Dim lType As Long

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

   ---->If Target.Column = 3 Then<----
        Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart
        varValues = cht.SeriesCollection(2).XValues
        lType = Target.Validation.Type
        If lType = 3 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            newVal = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            oldVal = Target.Value
            Target.Value = newVal
            If Target.Row > cht.SeriesCollection(2).Points(LBound(varValues) + 1) And Target.Row < cht.SeriesCollection(2).Points(UBound(varValues) + 1) Then
                If oldVal = "" Then
                Else
                    If newVal = "" Then
                    Else
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Ar = Split(oldVal, ", ")
                        strVal = ""
                        For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                            Debug.Print strVal
                            Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
                            If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
                                strVal = strVal
                                lCount = 1
                            Else
                                strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ", "
                            End If
                        Next i
                        If lCount > 0 Then
                            Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 2)
                        Else
                            Target.Value = strVal & newVal
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```